# Get the user roles with the keycloak userinfo endpoint

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

How can I get the the roles included in the reply of the userinfo endpoint in keycloak. I defined a "Role Mapping" for the user in keycloak. When I call the userinfo endpoint I get the fields like email name etc, but the roles are not included in the reply. When I call the auth endpoint I get the access_token and in the field scope has roles included. Here is the reply from the auth endpoint:

```
access_token" QJsonValue(string, "eyJhb...")
"expires_in" QJsonValue(double, 300)
"not-before-policy" QJsonValue(double, 0)
"refresh_expires_in" QJsonValue(double, 1800)
"refresh_token" QJsonValue(string, "eyJhb...")
"scope" QJsonValue(string, "profile email roles")
"session_state" QJsonValue(string, "20b48536-4b38-4aa6-9072-e8309833402e")
"token_type" QJsonValue(string, "bearer")
```

I also tried to call the userinfo endpoint with the attribute "scope=roles", but this didn't work.

Comment: if you un-parse accessToken, there are user roles for all clients you assigned to. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552003/how-to-decode-jwt-token-in-javascript-without-using-a-library

Comment: Bumblebee, I may be able to help you out here, but I need more details so a few questions: 1. Are you able to see the roles in decoded token? -try https://jwt.io/ for decoding your token 2. How are you trying to extract fields from token - through javascript library or Java library?

Comment: tryingToLearn, yes, I can decode the token in jwt.io and can also see the roles. I would like to extract the fields in a Qt5 C++ application.

Comment: I gave an answer related to this post's question in another one. [Here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75281326/3443964)

Answer (score 18):

As someone already mentioned, it's a bug. I heard it's fixed in latest version of keycloak.

I eventually fixed with this setting without upgrading to the fixed version of keycloak.

When you add User Realm Role, it will have **"realm_access.roles"** as Token Claim Name. You need to change it to **"roles"**. Then it will show correctly within userinfo.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Should be this issue: https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/resource-access-claim-missing-from-userinfo-until-i-change-the-name/1238

When renaming the claim in `Client Scopes -> roles -> Mappers -> realm roles/client roles`, i.e. `realm_access.roles` to `realm_accessy.roles` (and setting `Add to userinfo` to ON), it is included in userinfo :-/

Comment: The issue is fixed in Keycloak 12: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-9874

Comment: This is still broken in Keycloak 20.0.3 for Client Roles. With the default claim name of "resource_access.${client_id}.roles", the client roles were not included in userinfo. After changing the claim name to "client_roles" they are included.

Comment: edit: actually you can change the claim name to be the same as the default value and save it then it does work, so it seems the claim name default value is shown but not used until edited.

Answer (score 2):

In the mapper page on Keycloak, there is a setting called `Add to userinfo`, that has to be enabled.

Comment: Add to userinfo is alrady enabeled.

Answer (score 2):

For those whose above answer didn't work, I have spent the whole day figuring it out.
Basically, you have to go to client Scopes--> roles --> then move to Mappers tab, select client roles Add to Id token, access token and userinfo on

Here is the Screenshot
[image: Client Roles]