# Get roles from Keycloak userinfo endpoint

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, keycloak, openid-connect

I have keycloack realm with authorization code flow with public access type.

How can I get user roles from keycloak userinfo endpoint without client_secret?

I'm trying to use mappers but can't get this information.
Userinfo endpoint return only this:

```json
{
   "sub":"ace69576-614e-41fe-9584-aac69c34dec1",
   "email_verified":true,
   "name":"John Doe",
   "Token Claim Name":[
      "Realm Role prefixuma_authorization",
      "Realm Role prefixoffline_access"
   ],
   "preferred_username":"user",
   "given_name":"John",
   "family_name":"Doe",
   "email":"johndoe@example.com"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I get user roles from keycloak userinfo endpoint without
> client_secret?

Whether or not you can get the user roles from the *userinfo* endpoint is not related to the type of client (*i.e.,* `confidential` or `public`).

To make the user roles (*i.e.,* realm or/and client -related roles) also available from the *userinfo* endpoint do the following:

- Go to the according realm;
- Go to the according client;
- Go to Mappers;
- Click on `Create`;
- As the `Mapper Type` select `User Realm Role`;
- Set to `ON` the option `Add to userinfo`, and click Save;

If the user has client roles assigned to it; Repite the aforementioned steps but this time select `User Client Role` as the `Mapper Type`.

Comment: Good answer, thanks! But my old version of keycloak contains a bug described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64748129/12980819. Maybe this will help someone.