# Include groups (along with roles) in Keycloak token?

Tags: jwt, authorization, keycloak

Is there a way to include the list of *groups* a user is a member of inside a Keycloak access token, along with the roles they are in?  I've created several groups and mapped them to roles.  However, I may have more than 1 group that maps to a particular role.  I'd like to be able to make fine-grained authorization decisions so I know that *User A is in Role A but also Group B*.  Is that possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keycloak/OIDC : retrieve user groups attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56362197/keycloak-oidc-retrieve-user-groups-attributes)

Comment: Yup.  That's the exact link I used in my self-answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer to this [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56362197/keycloak-oidc-retrieve-user-groups-attributes).  All I had to do was add an additional mapper to my Client.  Worked like a charm.