# Why I can't see the groups in my JWT issued from Keycloak?

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, keycloak

In my client configuration in Keycloak I have enabled groups mapping:

[image]

[image]

and in my Spring Boot application I have a Controller that prints the `principal`:

```
@GetMapping("/account/me")
public ResponseEntity<Principal> me(Principal principal) {

    return ResponseEntity.ok(principal);
}
```

but it doesn't contains the group that I defined in Keycloak.

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56372674/11621071) there should be an additional section `other_claims`. But it is not added!

Why?

Comment: Be aware that roles != groups. Have you mapped your groups to realm roles, or did you intend to use a group mapper instead of role mapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot indicates that you are using a `User Realm Role` mapper. If you want to map the groups, you need to use a `Group Membership` mapper instead.